# visual studio 2010 "NOT RESPONDING"

Tags: compatibility, vb.net-2010

My problem is that every time I click the "Open" or "Create" project in Visual Studio 2010, my screen will always stuck at (FNOT RESPONDING).

I already used it before but when I uninstalled and reinstalled it again, then this problem happen to me.

What is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting everything in the `%temp%` directory, because even if you uninstalled it, there will be stuff left in the temp folder, if that didn't work try uninstall it with powerful tools like [IObit Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/en/advanceduninstaller.php).

If that didn't work either, try and report your problem to Microsoft using this email address : **`vsfeedback [at] microsoft [dot] com`**, they will respond immediately, another option that i can recommend is to install `Visual Studio Community 2017`, **it's completely free**.

**Finally i hope that i can you with your problem :)**

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. I try installing visual studio 2008 and there's no problem with, i can use it properly. i think the problem is in the visual studio 2010 installer or what ?

Comment: @ralphgonzales If it did work previously and you have use it before as you said above, then the the problem is not form the installer, and why going back to 200 when you can go forward to 2017?

Comment: i can't go now because our project requirements is to use 2010 not other version. but thanks a lot :)

now i see the problem "VSPerf Profiling Control Driver" the message is *The driver cannot be used due to compatibility issues* i think that's why my studio is not responding .

This is my first encounter to this problem can you help me ?

Comment: @ralphgonzales Are you using windows 8?

Comment: These links might help you : [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/profiler/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8/) , [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbba78c1-d872-4505-8f63-6f0f233aaffb/visual-studio-2010-profiler-error-vsp1398?forum=vstsprofiler).